# VKSdk how to set delegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, vk

I'm trying to make VKSdk work with Swift. Documentation says that I need to set delegate and in order to do this I have to do the following in Objective-c

```
VKSdk *sdkInstance = [VKSdk initializeWithAppId:YOUR_APP_ID];
[sdkInstance registerDelegate:delegate];
[sdkInstance setUiDelegate:uiDelegate];
```

In swift I try to do it like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    VKSdk.initializeWithAppId("1111111")
    VKSdk.registerDelegate(self)


}
```

But it says `Cannot convert value of type "ViewController" to expected argument type "VKSdk"`

How to do this correctly ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: added working code as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Working code below

```
let sdk = VKSdk.initializeWithAppId("111111")
sdk.registerDelegate(self)
```